# How to count number of times a particular word appears in a column?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have two tables:

`tblArtwork` has these columns: *AritstFirstName, ArtistLastName, TitleOfPiece, Year, Style, Price*

`tblPurchasaes` has these columns: *CustNumber, DateOfPurchase, Amount, TitleOfPiece*

I want to write a query that tells me if certain CustNumbers prefer certain Styles by analyzing their purchase history. There are thousands of CustNumbers that have purchased pieces of art having the same style. So, I want to count the number of times duplicate styles appear in each CustNumber's purchases. I have the following query:

```
with tblPreferredStyles as (
    select CustNumber, P.TitleOfPiece, Style
        , Count(Style) over (partition by CustNumber order by Style) as StyleTotal
    from tblPurchases as P
    join tblArtwork as A on P.TitleOfPiece = A.TitleOfPiece
)
select *
from tblPreferredStyles
```

which returns something like this:

| CustNumber | TitleOfPiece | Style | StyleTotal |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Whatever1 | StA | 2 |
| 1 | Whatever2 | StA | 2 |
| 1 | Whatever3 | StB | 5 |
| 1 | Whatever4 | StB | 5 |
| 1 | Whatever5 | StB | 5 |

The results in the StyleTotal column aren't counting what I want, and I'm not sure why. I would like the results to run like this: 2, 2, 3, 3, 3 since the first two pieces have the same style, and the next three pieces have the same style.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: @Olivier Thank you for the edit!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add `Style` to the `PARTITION BY` inside the `OVER` clause (and remove the `ORDER BY`):

```
WITH tblPreferredStyles AS (
SELECT 
    CustNumber, 
    P.TitleOfPiece, 
    Style,
    COUNT(Style) OVER(PARTITION BY CustNumber, style) as StyleTotal
FROM tblPurchases as P
INNER JOIN tblArtwork as A
    ON P.TitleOfPiece = A.TitleOfPiece
)
SELECT * 
FROM tblPreferredStyles;
```

Comment: Indeed, that did the trick. Thank you so much!